# What is the distinction between terms 'where', 'while', 'whereas' and 'whenever'?

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

It seems all of these four words can denote 'at the same time' or 'if and only if', but do the meanings of them identical?

Update: 
e.g.

1. Day comes where the sun rises.
2. Day comes whereas the sun rises.
3. Day comes while the sun rises.
4. Day comes whenever the sun rises.

Update: 
e.g.

1. An integer is even where it is divisible by 2.
2. An integer is even whereas it is divisible by 2.
3. An integer is even while it is divisible by 2.
4. An integer is even whenever it is divisible by 2.

Comment: I think this question would be better with some specific examples illustrating your context.

Comment: Perhaps if you added a bit more context, example sentences, and some explanation of what you have found out so far, this question might be a better fit for this site.

Comment: Can you give some example sentences where you think all four can replace one another?

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: None of them mean "if and only if" in fact in English only "*if and only if*" means 'if and only if'  but it can be abbreviated in formal logic proofs as [*iff*](http://xkcd.com/1033/).

Comment: A native speaker would say '*the sun*' instead of just 'sun' and they would say '*rises*' instead of 'arises'. The use of 'whereas' is not grammatical in this context.  As far as sentences 1,3, and 4, while they all make sense (using 'the sun rises.') they all mean different things so they are not interchangeable.

Comment: I take it back, I can make #2 grammatical by asking "So if we say the *day 'comes'* does the sun also *'come'*?" "No, day *'comes'*, whereas the sun *'rises'*."

Comment: OK, let me update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Whereas" does not match the other three, specifically "An integer is even whereas it is divisible by 2." is not a well-formed sentence.

"Whereas" indicates contrast, as in "I like tacos, whereas Jean likes hamburgers", etc.

"Whereas" can also be used in very formal contexts to indicate causality or logical flow, but I don't think the usage you cite works for this.

It is OK to say, "Whereas the sun has risen, day has come".  In this case the "whereas" indicates an implicit contrast to the absence of such evidence.

Comment: "Whereas the sun has risen, therefore day has come" is not grammatical.  In normal use, the adverb *[therefore](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/therefore)* is conjunctive and joins independent clauses (or an independent clause and a consequential phrase).  "Whereas the sun has risen" is not an independent clause, because of being preceded by conjunction *[whereas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereas)*.  On the other hand, "Whereas the sun has risen, day has come" is ok to say.  It is particularly ok if pomposity is the desired effect. "The sun has risen, therefore day has come" seems better.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @jwpat7.  I'll strike my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that "while" and "whereas" can have the same use, but not in the specific examples that you have given.

Here are their individual meanings:

where = at any place/ situation that

whereas = but on the other hand; while on the contrary (used to point out how two things are different)

while = at the same time that

whenever = at any time that

---

If you're looking for an expression that fits "if and only if," you could use "provided/ providing that" or "as long as"